# SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name

Tags: smtp-auth, learn-ruby-on-rails

currently I'm doing Daniel Kehoe's [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) tutorial. One of the exercises is to send a contact form from the Contact page using Google's Gmail account.

However, when I sent the contact form, instead of getting an email in my mailbox, I'm getting this error:

"SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name"

In my config/application.yml file, I set my Gmail username and password.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Rails 4.0 (Rails 4.1 uses a secrets.yml file to set credentials):

Check the file *config/environments/development.rb*, you should have this:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"],
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }
  # ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  # Send email in development mode.
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Try replacing ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] with your Gmail username.

You can set ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] in your Unix shell. Or set it in the file *config/application.yml*. If the username contains any non-alpha characters, you may need to enclose it in quotes in the file *config/application.yml*.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks. The issue is solved, I had typed 'username' instead of 'user_name'

Comment: Also for me, changing `username` into `user_name` solved the problem. I will refine @Daniel Kehoe answer into new Answer post.

Answer (score 6):

Just double check parameters name to be correct. For me changing `username` into `user_name` solved the problem.
If you like to see errors, change value of `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors` into `true`.
I have Rails 4 and it has not required any change of settings to working properly.
Thanks @Toontje and @Daniel Kehoe